# clang memory sanitizer; how to make it print source line numbers

Tags: clang++, msan

I'm compiling my program with `clang++ -fsanitize=memory -fsanitize-memory-track-origins -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -O0` and when I run it, the output is:

```
matiu@matiu-laptop:~/projects/json++11/build$ ./tests 
.......==10534== WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x7fe7602d4a51 (/home/matiu/projects/json++11/build/tests+0x106a51)
    #1 0x7fe7602dfca6 (/home/matiu/projects/json++11/build/tests+0x111ca6)
    ...
    #31 0x7fe75edbaec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec4)
    #32 0x7fe7602808dc (/home/matiu/projects/json++11/build/tests+0xb28dc)

  Uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation
    #0 0x7fe76026e7b3 (/home/matiu/projects/json++11/build/tests+0xa07b3)
    #1 0x7fe7602ee7da (/home/matiu/projects/json++11/build/tests+0x1207da)
    ...
    #18 0x7fe7602c1c4c (/home/matiu/projects/json++11/build/tests+0xf3c4c)
    #19 0x7fe7602873fa (/home/matiu/projects/json++11/build/tests+0xb93fa)

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value ??:0 ??
Exiting
```

How can I make it show line numbers like in the beautiful examples: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html

I'm suspecting it might not be possible, due to my pragram being one giant nested bunch of lambdas: https://github.com/matiu2/json--11/blob/master/tests.cpp

Comment: So it does print line numbers in examples, but not in your code? `addr2line` could be helpful, but not truly what you've asked for.

Comment: Thanks @keltar that definitely helps:

    $ addr2line -e tests 0x15c59a
    /.../bandit/src/bandit/bandit/grammar.h:126

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the address sanitizer I noticed that I needed to have these environment variables defined:

- `ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1` (only needed when compiled with GCC > 4.8) and
- `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=$(which llvm-symbolizer)` I think the symbolizer is what you're looking for. It transforms symbols to file names with line numbers and columns.

On the [memory sanitizer project website](https://code.google.com/p/memory-sanitizer/wiki/MemorySanitizer#Symbolization) it reads:

> Symbolization
>
> Set MSAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH environment variable to the path to
>   llvm-symbolizer binary (normally built with LLVM). MemorySanitizer
>   will use it to symbolize reports on-the-fly.

So you need `MSAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to be set analogous to `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, that was exactly what I needed :) It turns out, on my Ubuntu installation the llvm-symbolizer was named llvm-symbolizer-3.5 .. adding a symlink to it at /usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer and just having it in the path did the trick.

Comment: On Ubuntu, creating the symbolic link is still needed for the line numbers to be printed.

Comment: on ubuntu, you need `apt install llvm` (at least as of 18.04)

Comment: @matiu, in Ubuntu 20.10 the location is the expected one: `/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer`.