# C++ sanity check fails: several variables/memory positions are changed to garbage, even if I never acess them

Tags: c++, pointers, skip-lists

I'm implementing a Skip List. It's not important what it is, but it works right now for 1000 nodes but not with 10000. I was getting SegFaults that didn't made sense, so I printf'ed some variables. To my surprise, a lot of things that shouldn't were changing, to garbage values. For example, I printed inputValue before and after function insertNode. It sometimes resets to zero, when should always be incrementing. Let's see code (skip the read file input, the problem happens at the while cycle):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string filename = "";

    if( argc == 2 )
      filename = argv[1];
    else
        return 0;

    list = new skiplist();

    fstream inputFile(filename.c_str(), ios_base::in);

    inputFile >> numberofnodes;
    inputFile >> list->minimumKey;
    inputFile >> list->maximumKey;

    printf("%d\n", numberofnodes);
    printf("%d\n", list->minimumKey);
    printf("%d\n", list->maximumKey);

    list->Maxlevel = 1;

    list->header = new node();
    list->tail = new node();
    list->header->key = list->minimumKey;
    list->tail->key = list->maximumKey;


    for ( int i=1; i<=MAXIMUMLEVEL; i++ ) {
       list->header->forward[i] = list->tail;
       list->tail->forward[i] = NULL;
    }

    int sanityCheck = 134153;
    // insert nodes
    int inputKey;
    int inputValue = 0;
    int * keys = new int[numberofnodes];
    while (inputFile >> inputKey)
    {
        inputValue++;
        keys[inputValue] = inputKey;
        insertNode(inputKey, inputValue);  
        if(sanityCheck != 134153)       // dark magic changes this value
            keys[9999999999999999999999]++;  // program crashes here
                                             // it would otherwise crash on while
    }
    printf("\n\nNodes inserted: %d\n\n",inputValue);
```

I ran Valgrind. The invalid memory writes/read happened after and because of the variables changing, at least I believe so. That's why I added the sanity check. And as I thought, there were no invalid memory writes/read before trying to access keys[9999999999999999999999]. But that line can only run the int sanitycheck is changed, which I never do.

Finally, here's the code for the insertNode. I see nothing on it that could cause this:

```
void insertNode(int newKey, int newValue){
    node * update[MAXIMUMLEVEL];
    node * auxNode = list->header;
    for(int i=list->Maxlevel; i >=1; i--) {
        while ( auxNode->forward[i]->key < newKey ) {
            auxNode = auxNode->forward[i];
        }
        update[i] = auxNode;
    }
    auxNode = auxNode->forward[1];
    if ( auxNode->key == newKey ) {
        auxNode->value = newValue;
    } else {
        int randomLevel = 1;
        while ( (rand() / double(RAND_MAX)) < LEVELPROBABILITY && randomLevel < MAXIMUMLEVEL ) {
            randomLevel++;
        }

        if ( randomLevel > list->Maxlevel ) {
            for ( int i = list->Maxlevel+1; i <= randomLevel; i++ ) {
                update[i] = list->header;
            }
            list->Maxlevel = randomLevel;
        }
        node * newNode = new node();
        newNode->key = newKey;
        newNode->value = newValue;
        for ( int i=1; i<=MAXIMUMLEVEL; i++ ) {
            newNode->forward[i] = NULL;
        }

        for ( int i=1; i<=list->Maxlevel; i++ ) {
            newNode->forward[i] = update[i]->forward[i];
            update[i]->forward[i] = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

And the structures:

```
typedef struct node {
    int key;
    int value;
    node * forward[MAXIMUMLEVEL+1];
}node;

struct skiplist {
    int minimumKey;
    int maximumKey;
    int Maxlevel;
    node * header;
    node * tail;
};

EDIT:
#define MAXIMUMLEVEL 16 
#define LEVELPROBABILITY 0.5
```

I'm not even using mallocs. There are pointer operations, but valgrind should detect if I did something bad right? If I was running out of memory, there would be an exception. How is it possible that an int I create and never access/write/change gets modified? Sorry for the long post, but I have no idea where the problem might be.

Valgrind output without the sanity check (keys[999...9]): http://pastebin.com/hWH3fri2

Line 155 is the while (inputFile >> inputKey)

Comment: have you considered the possibility of overflowing the local variable `update` in `insertNode`? that's the only stack corruption I can spot right now

Comment: update your question with valgrind output.

Comment: Are you certain inputValue is always less than numberofnodes?

Comment: If you have no idea where the problem might be, you could try *narrowing it down* by simplifying the code. And you haven't given us the data file (and maybe not enough code to run, I'm not going to check), so we have the choice of 1) filling in the missing code/data by guesswork, or 2) trying to spot the bug by inspection in all the code above. You've been on this site long enough to know about [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you suppost this `keys[9999999999999999999999]` could be accessing your array out of bounds?

Comment: One check you might want to add is asserting that `inputValue < numberofnodes` inside the `while (inputFile >> inputKey)` loop

Comment: added link to full code and input file, added valgrind.  
inputValue starts a 0 and is incremented for each node/key that is read from the file and inserted in the list. so it should be on the last cycle numberofnodes-1.
update in insertNode is size 16 x the structure, and not changed. should have mentioned sooner.

Comment: added the assert. No change in error output.
@dyp :D if it wasn't clear, what happened is that I was getting SegFault because random variables were changing to non-sense values. So I added that int sanityCheck that is never modified to test it. And indeed, it is changed, the program enters the IF and crashes on keys[9999999999999999999999]. It was just to be sure that such a thing - that seems impossible to me - was really happening.

Comment: Why are you using `free` if there's no `malloc` in your code? Objects allocated via `new` must be deleted via `delete`.

Comment: @dyp good catch ty, I thought I had changed all the free's to delete's prevoiusly

Comment: After setting up `randomLevel` with the loop, we know only that `randomLevel <= MAXIMUMLEVEL`. If `randomLevel == MAXIMUMLEVEL`, you'll get an out-of-bounds access in the loop updating `update` via the condition `i <= randomLevel`. Declaring it as `node* update[MAXIMUMLEVEL+1];` seems to fix the issue, though I currently can't tell if that's the right thing to do.

Comment: I got very useful complaints from clang's address sanitizer btw.

Comment: @dyp Oh my saviour I think you got it. According to the skip-list paper that's how that cycle should be, but they often start counting from 1 instead of zero. I'll triple check if everything else is working, but so far so good! Looks solved. edit: Yep, everything looking good, even the other operations other than insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the output of clang's address sanitizer (after [setting it up properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24821628/420683)):

```
==15146==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address
0x7ffeb006bb80 at pc 0x0000004e093c bp 0x7ffeb006ba60 sp 0x7ffeb006ba58

WRITE of size 8 at 0x7ffeb006bb80 thread T0
    #0 0x4e093b in insertNode(int, int) skiplist.cpp:55:27
    #1 0x4e3385 in skiplist.cpp:160:9
    #2 0x7f40b2fcda3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x20a3f)
    #3 0x419508 in _start (a.out+0x419508)

Address 0x7ffeb006bb80 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 160 in frame
    #0 0x4e022f in insertNode(int, int) skiplist.cpp:35

  This frams has 1 object(s):
    [32, 160) 'update' <== Memory access at offset 160 overflows this variable
```

Line 55 refers to this:

```
void insertNode(int newKey, int newValue){
    node * update[MAXIMUMLEVEL];
    node * auxNode = list->header;
    for(int i=list->Maxlevel; i >=1; i--) {
        while ( auxNode->forward[i]->key < newKey ) {
            auxNode = auxNode->forward[i];
        }
        update[i] = auxNode;
    }
    auxNode = auxNode->forward[1];
    if ( auxNode->key == newKey ) {
        auxNode->value = newValue;
    } else {
        int randomLevel = 1;
        while ( (rand() / double(RAND_MAX)) < LEVELPROBABILITY && randomLevel < MAXIMUMLEVEL ) {
            randomLevel++;
        }

        if ( randomLevel > list->Maxlevel ) {
            for ( int i = list->Maxlevel+1; i <= randomLevel; i++ ) {
                update[i] = list->header; // line 55 <===================
            }
            list->Maxlevel = randomLevel;
        }
```

The loop

```
while ( (rand() / double(RAND_MAX)) < LEVELPROBABILITY && randomLevel < MAXIMUMLEVEL ) {
    randomLevel++;
}
```

guarantees that `randomLevel <= MAXIMUMLEVEL`. If `randomLevel == MAXIMUMLEVEL`, and `MAXIMUMLEVEL > list->Maxlevel`, then the loop in line 54 turns into:

```
for ( int i = list->Maxlevel+1; i <= MAXIMUMLEVEL; i++ ) {
    update[i] = list->header; // line 55 <===================
}
```

Note that `update` is declared as `node * update[MAXIMUMLEVEL];`. You'll get an out-of-bounds access.

---

I don't quite understand why your code seems not to access the 0th element of arrays. In my experience, it is also much easier to work with half-open-on-right ranges of the form `[0, length_of_array)` which leads to loops of the form

```
for(int i = 0; i < length_of_array; ++i)
```

Note the `<` instead of `<=`. Consistent use of half-open-on-right ranges can dramatically reduce the number of off-by-one errors.

A quick fix is to declare `update` just like `node::forward` as

```
node * update[MAXIMUMLEVEL + 1];
```

Note the `+1`.

A better fix is probably to rewrite the code such that it uses half-open-on-right ranges, where `MAXIMUMLEVEL` gets it's interpretation from the range `[0, MAXIMUMLEVEL)` and is no longer a maximum, but a supremum (and denotes the number of levels).

Comment: Very insightful, thank you for the help. I'll change my code and hopefully in the future avoid bad practises like using arrays only from position 1 forward. It was adaptation from pseudo-code and I got lazy. Cheers