# How to make Clang LeakSanitizer show source code references? Or where is (a.out+0xd4f39) in source code?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, clang, address-sanitizer

I'm not getting source code references in my clang LeakSanitizer output. What am I missing?

My question has a secondary target. If I can't get LeakSanitizer to show source code lines, how can I cross reference output like `(/home/x/a.out+0xd4f39)` to source code?

The clang docs have the following usage example...

https://releases.llvm.org/14.0.0/tools/clang/docs/LeakSanitizer.html

```
$ cat memory-leak.c

include <stdlib.h>
void *p;
int main() {
  p = malloc(7);
  p = 0; // The memory is leaked here.
  return 0;
}

clang -fsanitize=address -g memory-leak.c ; ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out
==23646==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
Direct leak of 7 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:

0 0x4af01b in __interceptor_malloc /projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:52:3

1 0x4da26a in main memory-leak.c:4:7

2 0x7f076fd9cec4 in __libc_start_main libc-start.c:287
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 7 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

But when I try their example on my system I get

```
$ clang -fsanitize=address -g memory-leak.c ; ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out

=================================================================
==67103==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 7 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x5558ea37af39  (/home/x/a.out+0xd4f39) (BuildId: 23165eb1ea7f2560b5067bb2c4436e6e17eb5ebb)
    #1 0x5558ea3bedd8  (/home/x/swrender/a.out+0x118dd8) (BuildId: 23165eb1ea7f2560b5067bb2c4436e6e17eb5ebb)
    #2 0x7fd945c9328f  (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x2328f) (BuildId: 1e94beb079e278ac4f2c8bce1f53091548ea1584)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 7 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

The source code output is missing. I'm using clang version 14.0.6 and the above example is taken from 14.0.0 documentation, which is the closest match I can find.

```
$ clang -v
clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` before your run

For example: `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/local/bin/llvm-symbolizer`

This is described on https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#symbolizing-the-reports

More detail in this answer, which is about MemorySanitizer, but the same rules seem to apply:

- [clang memory sanitizer; how to make it print source line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399485/clang-memory-sanitizer-how-to-make-it-print-source-line-numbers?rq=4)